# Google Analytics Ecommerce Not Tracking Safari & Firefox Transactions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm new to development and am having trouble getting Google Analytics to track ecommerce transactions in Safari and Firefox. The tag is firing successfully in Chrome. Below is the code I'm generating on my order page:

```
ga("require", "ecommerce");
      var gaInfo = {
          "id": resp.number,
          "affiliation": "Bivouac Ann Arbor",
          "revenue": resp.total,
          "shipping": resp.shipping,
          "tax": resp.tax
      };

      ga("ecommerce:addTransaction", gaInfo);

      for (var i = 0; i < resp.lineItems.length; i++) {
          var lineItemInfo = {
              "id": resp.number,
              "name": resp.lineItems[i].name,
              "sku": resp.lineItems[i].sku_id,
              "category": "",
              "price": resp.lineItems[i].cost,
              "quantity": resp.lineItems[i].quantity
      };

      ga("ecommerce:addItem", lineItemInfo);
      };

      ga("ecommerce:send");
```

Not sure why the code would work on one browser and not the others.